# How to get Constant Velocity for Spritekit Gravity

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, gravity, skphysicsworld

I am making a Tetris kind of game, where I want my blocks to fall at a constant velocity. I want to achieve it using SpriteKit Physics Words Gravity.

Problem is that gravity is necessarily acceleration and hence block start to move faster as they fall. I know I can turn gravity off and use actions to move the block but I wish to do it with gravity.

Is there a way to make the gravitational force in SpriteKit world a linear constant velocity?

Comment: What you want to do is to set the gravity to zero and just give each block a velocity in the direction you want them to travel. Then they'll move at a linear constant velocity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the default physics you will not achieve what you are looking for.

In the [definition](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsWorld_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsWorld/gravity) of Gravity in Spite Kit is clear that is a acceleration, so is no possible to achieve linear speed with it.

> A vector that specifies the gravitational acceleration applied to
>   physics bodies in the physics world.

---

But, you can have some workarounds to achieve the behavior you want.

1. Gravity Acceleration 0, and add speed to the falling object.
2. Limit the maximum Speed of an Object.
3. Do you own physics

I Think the best way to do it, with gravity working as default, is by limiting the maximum speed.

**2 - Limit the maximum Speed**

[Consulting this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549271/control-max-speed-in-sprite-kit)

In [didSimulatePhysics()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKScene/didSimulatePhysics), you can verify the speed of the object, and limit it.

Like this (Credits to @Andrew, in the original post)

```
- (void)didSimulatePhysics {
  if (node.physicsBody.velocity.x < MAX_SPEED_X) {
  node.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(MAX_SPEED_X, MAX_SPEED_Y);
 }
}
```

Comment: If gravity is off, and you are adding a certain velocity to the object, why do you need to limit the max velocity? By definition the velocity will remain the same.

Comment: Those are 3 different options... in the 2 approach you have gravity working as default, just limiting the maximum speed.

Comment: I see, makes sense, I will try option 2 tomorrow and report back.